# CRUD one-to-one relationship inserting data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a really simple two tables made with code-first approach with relationship one to one. I do not know what is the best way to insert data.

Since each trip has one coach should I have two CRUD pages one for trips one for coaches? But then would I need another page to link them up together?

What I'm asking is: is there a way to make on one CRUD page e.g. when creating a trip to add a coach to it.

```
public class Coach
    {
        public int CoachID { get; set; }
        public int Capacity { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Trip Trip { get; set; }
    }

public class Trip
    {
        public int TripID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public List<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public Coach Coach { get; set; }

    }
```

The issue that I'm facing right now is after adding trip I'm going to add a coach which has a dropdown to select for which trip do I want to add this coach and pressing create does nothing the page just stays the same nothing happens.
[image: Adding trip]
[image: Adding a coach]

Answer (score 2):

I would usually create method that are simple, does only one thing.

I would create two simple CRUD for both and have another service method that calls both 'Create' for Coach and 'Create' for Trip.

Comment: I've edited a little bit and added screenshots with the issue that I'm facing right now

Comment: not sure what the exact problem is..ils it the model binding the problem?, what error does it give?

Comment: are you using database?

Comment: Yeah built in sql express, no errors whatsoever it's just stuck nothing happens when I press create. (Controller and views were automatically generated so I know they should be working)

Comment: httppost method doesnt generate automatically did you create Httppost method?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that each form is actually wrapped in a form tag and that your buttons type is "submit". This should at least get you to your next step of figuring out how you would like to implement it.